# pari gp ínstallation in rpi

Tags: software-installation, c, software-compilation, gcc, perl

I am trying to compile one of a project with pari library dependency but i am facing below error while running the configuration file. Its installing just fine in ubuntu and windows but not here. I check gzip, perl, gcc, everything is already installed in rpi. Not sure whats the issue. Can someone please help me with this?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/mystuff/pari-2.15.3 $ ./Configure 
Configuring pari-2.15.3 (STABLE) 
Checking echo to see how to suppress newlines...
...using \c
Looking for some tools first ...
./Configure: 1: ./locate: Permission denied
...I could not find gzip.
./Configure: 1: ./locate: Permission denied
...I could not find cc.
./Configure: 1: ./locate: Permission denied
...I could not find gcc.
./Configure: 1: ./locate: Permission denied
...I could not find ld.
./Configure: 1: ./locate: Permission denied
...I could not find perl.
./Configure: 1: ./locate: Permission denied
...I could not find zcat.
./Configure: 1: ./get_archos: ./arch-osname: Permission denied
Choosing C compiler ...
###
### Could not find a C compiler. Please install cc/gcc or set $CC
###
```

I am using Raspberry 4, Model B , 2GB RAM

Comment: Use `sudo ./configure`